# mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

`table1` is the parent table with a column `ID` and `table2` has a column `IDFromTable1`.

Why when I put a FK on `IDFromTable1` to `ID` in `table1` do I get `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error`?

(I would like to delete the `table2` record if the `table1` record gets deleted.)

```
ALTER TABLE `table2`  
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK1` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`IDFromTable1`) REFERENCES `table1` (`ID`) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Both tables' engines are InnoDB. Both colmnns are type `char`. `ID` is the primary key in `table1`.

Comment: Also, check that the character sets for both tables are the same.

Comment: Please provide table definitions for table1 and table2. How did you get this error? Do you use a tool to create the foreign key? It seems that it is not a MySQL native error.

Comment: @user516883 - Do you need help to get table definitions? In HeidiSQL you can simply click on the **CREATE code** tab.

Comment: ...and what about table definitions? Run SHOW CREATE TABLE table1, then table2

Comment: I had the same error. I ran "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" and found out I didn't have the required privileges.

Using C-panel on a shared server didn't give me the privileges to ALTER, so I had to export the SQL, add the constraints and import.

Answer (score 648, accepted):

I ran into this same problem with HeidiSQL. The error you receive is very cryptic. My problem ended up being that the foreign key column and the referencing column were not of the same type or length.

The foreign key column was `SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED` and the referenced column was `INT(10) UNSIGNED`. Once I made them both the same exact type, the foreign key creation worked perfectly.

Comment: Or may be that the referenced column is not a primary key

Comment: Kinda similar problem for me--the referenced table didn't exist yet. Whoops.

Comment: I've totally experienced what Jake did, but I've ran into another FK issue (different type) on HeidiSQL. FK on varchars need to be the same collation. Hope that helps someone else in the future!

Comment: In addition and for **HeidiSQL** too, You may forgot set a primary key in the referenced table which should be the foreign key.

Comment: [Dumb mode on] If you set the FK field to have NOT NULL on an already populated table, MySQL will fill with 0 values... And when you try to add the constraint of course it will fail because you have no referenced record with PK = 0...

Comment: To add to @Amalgovinus - It ***DOES NOT tell you if referenced table doesn't exist***, it will just lie to you saying "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" .

Comment: In my case it was because of different Encoding and Collation.

Comment: @nawfal - I believe it does not necessarily have to be a primary key, but it MUST have an index. Primary keys automatically get indexed.

Comment: Yup, mine was mismatched signed/unsigned integer types.

Comment: No one mentioned partitioning. If your FK is a PK that is also the partition key, it will produce this error.

Comment: This comment helped me. In my case it was because of a different encoding "varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL" (generated by hibernate) against a foreign key defined with "varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL".

Comment: Also using HeidiSQL, resolved by changing the names of the FK's. They have to be unique!

Comment: For me it was 'id INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL' in one table, being referenced to by 'userid INT(5)'.

Just added UNSIGNED NOT NULL and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: I don't understand your answer, a few screenshots would be helpful

Comment: One field being unsigned and the other not will also cause this error!

Comment: In my case it's because I had "SET NULL" on a column that couldn't be NULL, mysql always so bad at explaining issues

Comment: In my case, it was because I had my composite foreign key columns in the wrong order compared to the composite pkey in the parent table. Still errored even though all my types and everything else matched.

Answer (score 158):

For anyone facing this problem, just run
`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`
and see the **LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR** section for details.

Comment: Awesome, this led me to the real error: `Field type or character set for column 'vehicle_id' does not match referenced column 'id'`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't now about this instruction, helped me figure out what went wrong.

Comment: This is by far the most efficient way to uncover the error, which could have numerous causes.

Comment: First off.. Dude.. My dude. Thank you! You'd think the "you have defined a SET NULL condition but column 'col' is defined as NOT NULL" would be in the actual error message??

Comment: Interesting. That showed exactly what was going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This inspired me to [improve](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/commit/cbd4854f4a2c63ba817599aa3b16c06676e69a5f) the error message in HeidiSQL, which now appends the relevant content from that `SHOW...` command.

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem when the parent table was created using `MyISAM` engine.  It's a silly mistake, which I fixed with:

```
ALTER TABLE parent_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was going crazy with this. Any idea why the database would suddenly switch the engine for tables?

Answer (score 48):

make sure columns are identical(of same type) and if reference column is not `primary_key`, make sure it is `INDEXED`.

Comment: It even happened to me that, there was no error, but foreign key was not added (1 was and 1 wasn't actually), but after adding simple `KEY referencing_column(referencing_column)` *BEFORE* both foreign keys definition they were both added successfuly :)

Comment: Keys not being indexed were my issue.

Comment: I had this issue and the problem was I had a dual column primary key and you can not use the 2nd column of the primary key as a foreign key. So I just added own index for the 2nd column of the primary key and then it worked.

Answer (score 26):

Syntax for defining foreign keys is very forgiving, but for anyone else tripping up on this, the fact that foreign keys must be "of the same type" applies even to collation, not just data type and length and bit signing.

Not that you'd mix collation in your model (would you?) but if you do, be sure your primary and foreign key fields are of the same collation type in phpmyadmin or Heidi SQL or whatever you use.

Hope this saves you the four hours of trial and error it cost me.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out my online host uses the ISAM engine and for local dev I use InnoDB.  When I backed up a table from the host to the local...boom.

Comment: Recent versions of MariaDB seem to use utf8_mb4 as the default charset (when not set explicitly in the server config) so `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` was my (unexpected) problem (on the dev machine).

Comment: Can't say about exactly four hours, but you definitely saved me a lot of wasted time and headaches!

Answer (score 22):

I had same problem, but solved it.

*Just make sure that column 'ID' in 'table1' has **UNIQUE** index!*

And of course the type, length of columns 'ID' and 'IDFromTable1' in these two tables has to be same. But you already know about this.

Comment: Unsure of the details, but I had a composite key with this error which was fixed by adding individual unique indexes for the columns.

Comment: The referenced column has to be indexed, it doesn't have to be unique (although that's the usual case).

Answer (score 20):

mysql error texts doesn't help so much, in my case, the column had "`not null`" constraint, so the "`on delete set null`" was not allowed

Comment: God bless you. I have been struggling with this for almost an hour now.

Comment: I ask myself - when I struggle in such cryptic error messages - who is proposing the error messages. May be there is a context _who can create the most cryptic and misleading error message_. Thank you! I had exactly this problem in the table design.

Answer (score 17):

Just for completion.

This error might be as well the case if you have a foreign key with VARCHAR(..) and the charset of the referenced table is different from the table referencing it.

e.g. VARCHAR(50) in a Latin1 Table is different than the VARCHAR(50) in a UTF8 Table.

Comment: Even utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci are causing the error

Comment: @S Doering, you're right. In addition to the missing definition of my foreign key (that is VARCHAR) as unique index (while it's not a primary key in the referenced table), I had to declare explicitly `COLLATE` with the same value of my origin table.

Comment: Oh yes! That was it for me... Executed Django migrations in a new different database and the default collation was another then the ones used before migrations... Thus I had OperationalError with foreignkey incorrectly formed, changing database collation to right one before migration fixed it for me... Thanks!

Comment: In my case I changed latin1 to utf8mb4 - and this fixed the problem

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, both columns were INT(11) NOT NULL but I wan't able to create the foreign key.
I had to disable foreign keys checks to run it successfully :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=OFF;
ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=ON;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This did  help me to pass further, but my problem was missing primmary index in column

Comment: I was encountering this issue after I deleted a table which had a foreign key constraint, and was trying to recreate the table and foreign key. Weird thing was, phpMyAdmin was telling me the foreign key had also been deleted, but MySQL was still throwing this error as if it still existed when I would run my create query. Restarting MySQL and then setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=OFF fixed whatever was wrong for my edge case, allowing me to create the table again.

Comment: This worked only for one of the tables, the rest I still get the same error. 
I assume there is some metadata column I am unaware of, or capitalization?

Comment: It certainly helped! I had to import a 3GB database created ages ago and FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=OFF did the trick! Thanks you!

Comment: In a Terminal you can use `mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" ...` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801445/7395683

Answer (score 12):

if everything is ok, just add `->unsigned();` at the end of `foreign key`.

if it does not work, check the datatype of both fields. they must be the same.

Comment: In my case "check the datatype of both fields. they must be the same" was my solution. Thank you, @josef :)

Answer (score 11):

One more probable cause for the display of this error. The order in which I was creating tables was wrong. I was trying to reference a key from a table that was not yet created.

Answer (score 7):

(Last Resent) Even if the field name and data type is the same but the collation is not the same, it will also result to that problem.

For Example

> TBL
>   NAME       |        DATA
>   TYPE          |
>           COLLATION
>
> ActivityID          |        INT                        |
>           **latin1_general_ci**
>       ActivityID          |        INT                        |
>           **utf8_general_ci**

Try Changing it into

> TBL
>   NAME       |        DATA
>   TYPE          |
>           COLLATION
>
> ActivityID          |        INT                        |
>           **latin1_general_ci**
>       ActivityID          |        INT                        |
>           **latin1_general_ci**

....

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

This problem also occur in `Laravel` when you have the foreign key table `table1` migration after the migration in which you reference it `table2`.

You have to preserve the order of the migration in order to `foreign key` feature to work properly.

```
database/migrations/2020_01_01_00001_create_table2_table.php
database/migrations/2020_01_01_00002_create_table1_table.php
```

should be:

```
database/migrations/2020_01_01_00001_create_table1_table.php
database/migrations/2020_01_01_00002_create_table2_table.php
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the tables engine, both tables have to be the same engine, that helped me so much.

Comment: Good point! I am dealing with a Zen Cart database in MySQL whose tables are all in the MyISAM engine by default.  I added a table using InnoDB engine, and tried to add a foreign key constraint from my table to the core Zen Cart one.  It failed with this obscure 'incorrectly formed' error.  You can see the engine for each table with `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name';`

Answer (score 4):

Although the other answers are quite helpful, just wanted to share my experience as well.

I faced the issue when I had deleted a table whose `id` was already being referenced as foreign key in other tables (*with data*) and tried to recreate/import the table with some additional columns.

The query for recreation (generated in phpMyAdmin) looked like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `the_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,            /* No PRIMARY KEY index */  
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_fa` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_pa` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

... /* SOME DATA DUMP OPERATION */

ALTER TABLE `the_table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), /* PRIMARY KEY INDEX */
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uk_acu_donor_name` (`name`);
```

As you may notice, the `PRIMARY KEY` index was set after the creation (*and insertion of data*) which was causing the problem.

#### Solution

The solution was to add the `PRIMARY KEY` index on table definition query for the `id` which was being referenced as foreign key, while also removing it from the `ALTER TABLE` part where indexes were being set:

```
CREATE TABLE `the_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,            /* <<== PRIMARY KEY INDEX ON CREATION */  
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_fa` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_pa` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Its worked for me. I was worried that I need to reinstall my software ;)

Answer (score 4):

I lost for hours for that!

PK in one table was `utf8` in other was `utf8_unicode_ci`!

Answer (score 3):

Try running following:

```
show create table Parent

//and check if type for both tables are the same, like myISAM or innoDB, etc
//Other aspects to check with this error message: the columns used as foreign 
keys must be indexed, they must be of the same type 
(if i.e one is of type smallint(5) and the other of type smallint(6), 
it won't work), and, if they are integers, they should be unsigned.

//or check for charsets
show variables like "character_set_database";
show variables like "collation_database";

//edited: try something like this
ALTER TABLE table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_IdTable2
FOREIGN KEY (Table1_Id)
REFERENCES Table1(Table1_Id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Try running SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to get some more details on the error

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti - +1!  That did it for me.  The details are helpful.  Was able to fix the problem quickly.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti thank you man, For anyone facing this problem, run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and check the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section.

Answer (score 3):

My case was that I had a typo on the referred column:

```
MariaDB [blog]> alter table t_user add FOREIGN KEY ( country_code ) REFERENCES t_country ( coutry_code );
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `blog`.`t_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

The error message is quite cryptic and I've tried everything - verifying the types of the columns, collations, engines, etc.

It took me awhile to note the typo and after fixing it all worked fine:

```
MariaDB [blog]> alter table t_user add FOREIGN KEY ( country_code ) REFERENCES t_country ( country_code );
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.039 sec)              
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems.

The issue is the reference column is not a primary key.

Make it a primary key and problem is solved.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a PK, it can also be UNIQUE NOT NULL.

Comment: Actually...in my case simply setting it to an index type normal worked.

Answer (score 2):

thanks S Doerin:

*"Just for completion.
This error might be as well the case if you have a foreign key with VARCHAR(..) and the charset of the referenced table is different from the table referencing it.
e.g. VARCHAR(50) in a Latin1 Table is different than the VARCHAR(50) in a UTF8 Table."*

i solved this problem, changing the type of characters of the table.
the creation have latin1 and the correct is utf8.

add the next line.
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

Comment: This was my case too. my collation were different for the Varchar type, as soon as I changed the collation with phpMyAdmin Client everything worked

Answer (score 2):

I face this problem the error came when you put the primary key in different data type like:

**table 1:**

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('product_name');
        });
```

**table 2:**

```
Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('brand_name');
        });
```

the data type for id of the second table must be **increments**

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling as I was with this issue, this was my problem:

I was trying to alter a table to change a field from VARCHAR(16) to VARCHAR(255) and this was referencing another table column where the datatype was still VARCHAR(16)...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Symfony 2.8.

I didn't get it at first, because there were no similar problems with int length of foreign keys etc.

Finally I had to do the following in the project folder. (A server restart didn't help!)

`app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
 app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`

Answer (score 1):

I was using **HeidiSQL** and to solve this problem I had to **create an index in the referenced table** with all the columns being referenced.

[image: adding index to table Heidisql]

Comment: Same for me in mysql : InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues using Alter table to add a foreign key between two tables and the thing that helped me was making sure each column that I was trying to add a foreign key relationship to was indexed. To do this in PHP myAdmin:
Go to the table and click on the structure tab.
Click the index option to index the desired column as shown in screenshot:

[image]

Once I indexed both columns I was trying to reference with my foreign keys, I was able to successfully use the alter table and create the foreign key relationship. You will see that the columns are indexed like in the below screenshot:

[image]

notice how zip_code shows up in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue just now. In my case, all I had to do is to make sure that the table I am referencing in the foreign key must be created prior to the current table (earlier in the code). So if you are referencing a variable (x*5) the system should know what x is (x must be declared in earlier lines of code). This resolved my issue, hope it'll help someone else.

Comment: I've had the same problem in MariaDB v10.3.18. We used MySQL before and it warned that a foreign key pointed to a non-existent table.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is very simple to solve**

e.g: you have two table with names **users** and **posts** and you want create **foreign key** in **posts** table and you use **phpMyAdmin**

1) in **post** table add **new column**
(**name**:use_id | **type**: like the **id** in **user** table | **Length**:like the **id** in **user** table | **Default**:NULL | **Attributes**:unsigned | index:INDEX )

2)on **Structure** tab  go to **relation view** 
(**Constraint name**: auto set by phpmyAdmin | **column name**:select user_id |**table**:users | **key**: id ,...)

**It was simply solved**

> javad mosavi   iran/urmia

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I discovered that on my own case, one table was MyISAM, and the other one INNO. Once I switched the MyISAM table to INNO. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution which I was missing here is, that each primary key of the referenced table should have an entry with a foreign key in the table where the constraint is created.

Answer (score 0):

If U Table Is **Myisum** And New Table Is **InoDb** you Are Note **Foreign**
You Must Change **MyIsum** Table To InoDb

Answer (score 0):

### Table Name is CASE Sensitive:

In my case, the problem was incorrect table name. My table name was `Users` and I wrongly defined the foreign key as `.. REFERENCES user(id)`. (Note the uppercase `U` in user).

Answer (score 0):

`errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed` also appears when you try to reference a key from a partitioned table. Remember that you cannot have references to the pk of partitioned tables.

Answer (score 0):

Another Laravel issue can be the order in the down method, you have to drop the referencing table first. Hope that makes sence !

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with Laravel 5.1 migration Schema Builder with MariaDB 10.1.

The issue was that I had typed `unigned` instead of `unsigned`(the `s` letter was missing) while setting the column.

After fixing the typo error was fixed for me.

Answer (score -1):

Even i ran into the same issue with mysql and liquibase.
    So this is what the problem is:
    The table from which you want to reference a column of other table is different either in case of datatype or in terms of size of the datatype.

```
Error appears in below scenario:
Scenario 1:
Table A has column id, type=bigint
Table B column referenced_id type varchar(this column gets the value from the id column of Table A.)
Liquibase changeset for table B:

    <changeset id="XXXXXXXXXXX-1" author="xyz">
            <column name="referenced_id" **type="varchar"**>
        </column>
            </changeset>
    <changeSet id="XXXXXXXXXXX-2" author="xyz">
                <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="FK_table_A"
                    referencedTableName="A" **baseColumnNames="referenced_id**"
                    referencedColumnNames="id" baseTableName="B" />
    </changeSet>

Table A changeSet:

    <changeSet id="YYYYYYYYYY" author="xyz">
     <column **name="id"** **type="bigint"** autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
                </column>
    </changeSet>

Solution: 
correct the type of table B to bigint because the referenced table has type bigint.

Scenrario 2:
The type might be correct but the size might not.
e.g. :
Table B : referenced column type="varchar 50"
Table A : base column type ="varchar 255"

Solution change the size of referenced column to that of base table's column size.
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that you've specified name of the table in the proper case (if table names are case-sensitive in your database). In my case I had to change

```
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PURCHASE_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

to

```
 CONSTRAINT `FK_PURCHASE_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

note the `customer` changed to `CUSTOMER`.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use DBDesigner4 which has a graphical interface to create your database and linking them using FK. Right click on your table and select 'Copy Table SQL Create' which creates the code.

[image]