# what is Correct syntax for executing sql syntax?

Tags: mysql

```
String ag ="ALTER TABLE QUESTION"+
            "(ADD  FOREIGN KEY (a_status) REFERENCES ANSWER(a_status))";

                      stmt.executeUpdate(ag);
```

> Error message:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY
>   (a_status) REFERENCES ANSWER(a_status))' at line 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Foreign Key to existing table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table)

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct. See the [offical documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
String ag ="ALTER TABLE QUESTION ADD FOREIGN KEY (a_status) REFERENCES ANSWER(a_status)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String ag ="ALTER TABLE QUESTION ADD CONSTRAINT (question_answer_ibfk1) FOREIGN KEY (a_status) REFERENCES ANSWER(a_status)";
```

In general

```
ALTER TABLE Child_tblName
ADD CONSTRAINT 'give any name to the foreign key generally I do Child_tblName_Parent_tblName_ibfk_number' FOREIGN KEY ('Child_tblName's Column') REFERENCES Parent_tblName('Parent_tblName's Column')
```

Comment: thank you sir **@Ole Albers!** for adding the good CodeBlock view for better readability , I am new to stackoverflow so learning these edition things.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ag ="ALTER TABLE QUESTION ADD CONSTRAINT (question_answer_fk1) FOREIGN KEY (a_status) REFERENCES ANSWER(a_status)";
```

Also you can have more condition specific to add:

- ON DELETE SET NULL/CASCADE
- ON UPDATE SET NULL