# Error code foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE `table_A` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `APPLICATION` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `APPLICATION_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`APPLICATION`),
   key `table_A_fk` (`APPLICATION_ID`),
   CONSTRAINT `table_A_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`APPLICATION_ID`) REFERENCES `table_B` (`APP_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB       

CREATE TABLE `table_B` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `APP_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `APP_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`APP_NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I need add a foreign key in `table_A` column name is `(Application_id)` with reference table being `table_B` column `(APP_NAME)`
   could you please help us on above code I have error with code 1215 ?

Comment: Please post the whole error you receive, literally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table

Answer (score 0):

1. To define a foreign keys in mysql the referenced field of the parent table must be indexed.

   > KEY ( APP_NAME )
2. Table_B needs to be created prior to Table_A in order to set a foreign key referencing to it.