# How to Refer Foreign Key table to refer another table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have Two Table Two Table Name called Following on this

```
1. TP_Users
2. TP_Roles
```

`TP_Users` Have Following Fields

```
Id (PK, int, not null)
UserName (nvarchar(50), null)
UserEmail (nvarchar(50), null)
DisplayName (nvarchar(50), null)
Password (nvarchar(50), null)
RoleId (FK, int, not null)
IsActive (bit, not null) ------>Foreign Key Reference 
ClientId (int, null)
```

`TP_Roles` have Following Fields

```
Id  PK, int, not null
Role_Name   varchar(200), null
IsActive    bit, null
```

`TP_Users`  Parent table  column name `RoleId` its  Refrenced table  `TP_Roles`       column name `id`.
How to make  relationships and how the link two tables using query ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table

Comment: use a join by roleId to communicate both tables

Comment: @cralfaro its not necessary Fk key? please explain  little bit more

Comment: Which DB MSSQL or MYSQL

Comment: @thenna I added a response with a possible example of what you need on MySql db engine, i did the example with not all yours fields, add them please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [forieng key constraint](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/prevent-truncate-table-on-sql-server-database-using-foreign-key-constraint.aspx) on your users table as follows

```
create table TP_Users
(
....., --- column list here
constraint FK_TP_Users_RoleId foreign key(RoleId) references TP_Roles(Id)
)
```

Then by using a simple inner join on related fields, you can build your query

```
select * 
from TP_Users
inner join TP_Roles on TP_Roles.Id = TP_Users.RoleId
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an example for the **MySQL** database language, how to create both tables and a simple query to join them.

```
CREATE TABLE TP_USERS (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME varchar(50),
  ROL_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`ROL_ID`) REFERENCES `TP_ROLES` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE TP_ROLES (
   ID int(11) NOT NULL,
   ROL_NAME varchar(50),
   IS_ACTIVE tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here a simple query where you can join both tables:

```
select u.USER_NAME, r.ROL_NAME from TP_USERS u, TP_ROLES r where u.ROL_ID=r.ID
```