# How to add a foreign key column in the MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `payment_request` in the MySQL and the

`DESCRIBE payment_request` provides the following output,

[image]

The `oderbook` table is provided below,

[image]

I want to add the `id` from the `payment_request` table in the `orderbook` as the foreign key with the name as `payment_request_id` after the `id` column (2nd position).

What will be the SQL to run the MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Foreign Key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table)

Comment: Let's keep it as mentions that we need to match the variable type for the declaration of the foreign key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add new column in table `orderbook`

```
ALTER TABLE orderbook
ADD payment_request_id INT(10) unsigned AFTER ID;
```

Then add a contraint that will define the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE orderbook
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_orderbook FOREIGN KEY (payment_request_id) 
REFERENCES payment_request (id);
```

Reference:

- [MySQL Alter Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: The last 3 commands to add the foreign key doesn't execute and I get the error: `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: @Arefe, because the data type are not matching. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

or by altering the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

Also refer to [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer