# Mysql cross database foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

I am trying to create a foreign key between `ticket` table of `task_flow` database with `user` table of `sardia` database:

- user_id  int(10)     UNSIGNED  No
- Id   int(10)     UNSIGNED      No

I created the query

```
ALTER TABLE ticket
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_u_id
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES sardia.user(Id);
```

> "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
>   Can somebody help how I can achieve this?

Comment: The definition looks correct to me.  Perhaps you have bad characters in the code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the full error is Can't create table `task_flow` Foreign key.. why does it say cant create.. database name?

Comment: To all those who might have the same problem,I had forgoten to set the users id column as primary key.Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has already ask something related to it, [click here to see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028214/add-foreign-key-to-existing-table).

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ticket ADD grade_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE ticket ADD CONSTRAINT fk_u_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES sardia.user(Id);
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing