# Disabling foreign key checks on the command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, foreign-keys, mysqlimport

I have a backup script for my MySQL database, using `mysqldump` with the `--tab` option so it produces a `.sql` file for the structure and a `.txt` file (pipe-separated) for the content.

Some tables have foreign keys, so when I import it I'm getting the error:

> ERROR 1217 (23000) at line 8: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

I know about using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` (and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` afterward). If I add those to each `.sql` file then the import works. But then obviously on the next `mysqldump` those get overwritten.

I also tried running it as a separate command, like below but the error comes back:

```
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" | mysql [user/pass/database] 
[all the imports]
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1" | mysql [user/pass/database]
```

Is there some other way to disable FK checks on the command line?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do this by concatenating the string to the file inline.  I'm sure there's an easier way to concatenate strings and files, but it works.

```
cat <(echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;") imports.sql | mysql
```

I don't think you need to set it back to 1 since it's just one session.

Comment: This looks like the best way. It's surprising `mysqldump` doesn't have a `--disable-foreign-keys` option.

Comment: @Barmar remember that foreign keys are a product of the InnoDB engine rather than MySQL itself

Comment: Thanks, that is working! So setting FK checks only works for one command, rather than persisting across multiple commands?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I think that it's per-session (run of the `mysql` command)

Comment: @ExplosionPills @Barmar just ran into another issue, how would I disable FK checks on the actual data import? My table has an FK to itself that may reference a later ID. My import command is `mysqlimport [user/pass] --local --fields-terminated-by="|" database "table.txt"`

Comment: Don't use the --tab option, just do a normal mysqldump so the data is in the .sql file. Then this answer should work.

Comment: Anybody know how to do this in Windows? :/

Comment: For windows you can use `mysql -u root wotr -p < "echo SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0"  < dump.sql`

Answer (score 177):

You can also use `--init-command` parameter of `mysql` command.

I.e.: `mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" ...`

[MySQL 5.5 Documentation - mysql options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_init-command)

Comment: This is the best solution, better than the answer of "Explosion Pills"

Comment: i tried like : mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u root -p DBname   and i get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u root -p DBName' at line 1

Comment: mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u root -p DBNAME < importNAME.sql

Comment: also you must be in the folder where your mysql script is located. For example I use xampp so it would be: C:\\xampp\mysql\bin

Comment: this is the answer.

Answer (score 31):

Login to mysql command line:

`mysql -u <username> -p -h <host_name or ip>` Then run

1 `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

2.`use <database_name>`

3 `SOURCE /pathToFile/backup.sql;`

4 `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

5 `exit`

Comment: I'm confused. Don't your instructions imply that you *should* be running this directly from the MySQL command line?

Comment: You may want to update your answer to clarify that then. Currently it says do *not* run directly from MySQL command line

Comment: don't forget to select database by using the following command before step2:
2) USE <database name>

Comment: this is my preferred method for uploading parent and child tables in no particular order.  UPVOTED!  ;)

Comment: This is not an option to disable from the command line, it is for the client.

Comment: Perfect ans! what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: No luck, mysql showed the errors and continued with the import. Because the errors were somewhere half-way the import, I didn't notice them at first, thinking the import succeeded, but it was not :-( I ended up fixing the foreign key constraints in the SQL file.

Comment: Totally a different way to do mysql imports. wow. And Im using mysql for 15 years. ouch.

Answer (score 16):

Just another one to do the same:

```
{ echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" ; cat imports.sql ; } | mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect since I was `zcat`ing my other file.

Answer (score 11):

Another way with .gz files:

`gunzip < backup.sql.gz | mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -u <username> -p`

Answer (score 0):

Based off the comments and answers, I ended up using this for a zipped database import with both InnoDB and MyISAM:

```
{ echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;" ; zcat dump.gz ; } | mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can call any command from cmd, this way:

```
mysql -e "SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
```

Of course, you need to specify the username, password and host using -u, -p and -h