# Any way to disable foreign key checks with mysqlimport tab option?

Tags: mysql, command-line, foreign-keys, mysqlimport

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938786/disabling-foreign-key-checks-on-the-command-line) before and I am just coming back to the issue.

> I have a backup script for my MySQL database, using `mysqldump` with the `--tab` option so it produces a `.sql` file for the structure and a `.txt` file (pipe-separated) for the content.

The answer on the linked question works when importing SQL files (the table structure), but I also get the foreign key constraint error when importing some tables (because the table has a foreign key to itself). The two commands are like this:

```
cat <(echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;") "table.sql" | mysql [user/pass] database
mysqlimport [user/pass] --local --fields-terminated-by="|" database "table.txt"
```

It looks like this has been [requested years ago on their bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19996) but never implemented. Is there any way around it?

Note that I want to continue using the tab option for various reasons (it's faster, and works better with git as each row is on a separate line).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always set temporarily the mysql global system variable 'foreign_key_checks' to off/zero value by following command line before running the database creation script.

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=USER --password -e "SET GLOBAL foreign_key_checks=0"
```

It is not secure to type the password on the command line. Omitting it and only specifying `--password` rather than `--password=MYPATH` will force the system to ask the user for it before proceeding.