# mysql import specific databse and disable foreignkey constraints

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have a full mysql backup with all databases but want to import just one of them by shell. So I used the "-D" option to specify the database I want to import. But how can I disable foreignkey constraints this way?

The dump file is about 2GB big, so I cant just write the command in the beginning of the file.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938786/disabling-foreign-key-checks-on-the-command-line

Comment: Found another solution. Create a newFile with all neccesary commands and than "cat oldDump >> newFile" :)