# create a sql backup file in php with tables in order of reference table first in sql file

Tags: php

I have created a script that will create a sql backup file, but after executing that backup file I am getting (error 150). Its because the sql tables contains foreign key reference and those are written in sequential order. How to correct the order of writing of sql file through php?

Comment: You can enclose it in a transaction... have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: [related: (temporarily) skip foreign key checks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938786/disabling-foreign-key-checks-on-the-command-line).