# MySQL error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am having trouble to solve this, I have this create statement:

```
create table `roles` 
(
    `name` varchar(255) not null,
    `description` varchar(255) not null, 
    `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, 
    `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null
) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But I am getting error:

`Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong here ?

FYI, I am using MySQL.

Actual statement is run using Laravel migration which gives error:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('name')->unique()->primary();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't even have an FK constraint shown in that one table schema with no relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken a quick look around and came across this SO question that does a good job of explaining why this error may occur: [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

What does this mean for you? It means that you have a foreign key field somewhere that is expecting to be populated with the primary key from your roles table, but the types between the two differ. I would imagine that in another table somewhere you have a column such as `role_id` that is int, bigint, tinyint, etc. Either way, you shouldn't be using strings as primary keys.