# Mysql workbench Error while applying SQL script to the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ')
>       REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON U' at line 10

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`instructor_profile` (
  `InstructorId` INT NULL,
  `InstructorName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `companyId` INT NULL,
  `companyName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `instructorEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ManagerName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ManagerEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `UserId`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `VendorId`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`vendor` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: To anyone finding this on Google: make sure your table engine matches, was an issue for this error in my case; see (and maybe upvote) here [*mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error/34274215#34274215)

Comment: @aexl Thank you, that was my issue, table engines weren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put a column name inside the parentheses, as others have said. This must match one of the column names previously given in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the column you want to reference and the column of the FK :

```
 CONSTRAINT `UserId`
      FOREIGN KEY (<TheColumn>)
      REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` (<TheColumnInTheOtherTable>)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `VendorId`
      FOREIGN KEY (<TheSecondColumn>)
      REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`vendor` (<TheSecondColumnInTheOtherTable>)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write name of the foreign key in parenthesis, yours are currently empty.

Answer (score 0):

You haven´t set the columns on which you want to set the foreign keys!

```
 CONSTRAINT `UserId`
    FOREIGN KEY ( `#KEYCOLUMN#` )
    REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` ( `#KEYCOLUMN#` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `VendorId`
    FOREIGN KEY ( `#KEYCOLUMN#` )
    REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`vendor` ( `#KEYCOLUMN#` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: even after adding foreign key, Im getting the error

Answer (score 0):

The operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''UserId')
>       REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION ' at line 10 SQL Statement: CREATE TABLE `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`instructor_profile` (   `InstructorId` INT NOT
>   NULL,   `InstructorName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   `companyId` INT NULL,
>   `companyName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   `ManagerName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
>   `ManagerEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,   `InstructorEmail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
>   CONSTRAINT `UserId`
>       FOREIGN KEY ('UserId')
>       REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`user` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON UPDATE NO ACTION,   CONSTRAINT `VendorId`
>       FOREIGN KEY ('VendorId')
>       REFERENCES `ad_d19fb99c240e6c8`.`vendor` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

still the error exists

Comment: This area is for answers to your question. Please edit your question instead of posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Because your new user doesn't have Privileges in MySQL Workbranch under User and Privileges
tab Administrative Roles and Privileges give access to user