# can't create a foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have created 2 tables at mysql then i am adding a new constraint for a foreign key between them , here are the tables .

```
create TABLE post
(
   post_id NUMERIC (5) NOT NULL ,
   post_username varchar (30) NOT NULL ,
   post_category_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL ,
   post_date TIMESTAMP ,
   post_reporting numeric (3) ,
   post_text varchar(2000) ,
   post_photo varchar(200)
);
alter TABLE post add CONSTRAINT po_pk PRIMARY KEY (post_id , post_username , post_date) ;

/*comment*/
create table comment
(
  comment_username varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
  comment_post_id NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL ,
  comment_post_username VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL ,
  comment_post_date TIMESTAMP,
  comment_date TIMESTAMP ,
  comment_text varchar(2000) ,
  comment_photo varchar(200)
);
alter table comment add CONSTRAINT co_pk PRIMARY KEY (comment_username,comment_date,comment_post_date,comment_post_id,comment_post_username);
```

then , when i add a new constraint for the foreign key as following

```
ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT com_ps_un_fk FOREIGN KEY (comment_post_date)
REFERENCES post(post_date);
```

i receive `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`
, both attributes are having the same datatype of `TIMESTAMP` i also tried another probabilities for both of them such as making them both `NULL` , `NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and the same as `NOT NULL` but nothing seemed to work .

Comment: Is there any content in comment table?

Comment: from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error) answer: both columns must be of same type AND LENGTH.

Comment: jophap no they have nothing , i have just created them

Comment: hossam , they already have the same datatype .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_date` is a part of a primary key. So, it can't be used as a key independently.

You have to make an `index` key on it. then, you would be able to make the relation:

```
ALTER TABLE `post` ADD INDEX(`post_date`);

ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT com_ps_un_fk FOREIGN KEY (comment_post_date)
REFERENCES post(post_date);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/364c8f)

Comment: saved my life !

Comment: @Amr, glad to help :)