# Laravel Migration: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using migrations to change a field to nullable(), using the following code.

```
$table->integer('recipe_id')->nullable()->change();
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './blackfisk/#sql-2
2d_a' to './blackfisk/preparations' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
incorrectly formed") (SQL: ALTER TABLE preparations CHANGE recipe_id recipe
_id INT DEFAULT NULL)
```

I've tried setting the foreign key checks to 0 using

```
    \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
```

But it's giving the same error. When I try to run the query in Sequel Pro I also get this error, using the following query.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE preparations CHANGE recipe_id recipe_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Any idea If I'm missing something here? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but they are the same field type (INT 10)

Comment: Tables are using same engine? InnoDB, MyISAM?

Comment: Yes,  they are, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create an unsignedInteger

```
$table->UnsignedInteger('recipe_id')->nullable()->change();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @Notflip  i am glad it helped you :).