# Strange foreign key error with MySQL under MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, mariadb

For some context, I am creating a javascript bot for discord and I'm creating a large database so that I can log many different pieces of information.

This part of the database is used so that I can

1. store messages
2. store historical messages, with every edit
3. easily look up which users are mentioned within these historical messages.

I am using MariaDB with MySQL Workbench under arch linux.
[Here's the relevant part of the database design, done on dbdesigner.net.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKMcQ.png)
 The problem happens at the left-most table.

And here's my error message:

> Finished executing script    ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 158: Can't
>   create table `test`.`#sql-1bb_6` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
>   is incorrectly formed")   Operation failed with exitcode 1

So I know that there's a problem with my foreign key at like 158 but I can't find the problem.

```
ALTER TABLE `messageContentHistoryMentions` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `messageContentHistoryMentions_fk1` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`messageContentCount`) REFERENCES `messageContentHistory`(`messageContentCount`);
```

The part that puzzles me about this is that 158 is formatted in the exact same way as line 156, only with different fields. Line 156 below runs:

```
ALTER TABLE `messageContentHistoryMentions` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `messageContentHistoryMentions_fk0` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`messageID`) REFERENCES `messageContentHistory`(`messageID`);
```

You can probably understand why I am very confused.
Some more information:

- This is a new install of MariaDB so assume defaults
- InnoDB is the engine being used
- The tables all have a collation of `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- Both sides of the foreign key are primary keys, are integer and have a length of 8, default of 0.

Thanks.
edit: this is not a duplicate as while the error is similar, the situation it is in is very different

Comment: 150 often means that the constraints were applied in the wrong order.

Comment: See [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: It's likely because `messageID` is already an index, such as a primary key, and the other field is not. So, make sure that `messageContentCount` is indexed for the `messageContentHistory` table.

Comment: @PaulT. Both fields are primary keys

Comment: @Sobeston: ...right, but it was likely not indexed. I see that **elenst** already answered, so no big deal. I basically said that the same thing to the first part of the answer, but he added the additional alternative to do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced table, in your case `messageContentHistory`, must have an index where the referenced columns, in your case `messageContentCount`, are listed as the **first** columns (in the given order). According to the schema, `messageContentCount` is a part of the primary key, but not the first part. `messageID` **is** the leftmost part of the primary key, that's why it works for it.

Try to add another index on `messageContentCount`:

```
ALTER TABLE messageContentHistory ADD KEY (messageContentCount);
```

It should work after that.

Alternatively, if it suits your purposes, you can add one foreign key on (`messageID`,`messageContentCount`) instead of the two separate ones. It should work too, because in this case the condition will be met.

[MariaDB KB for foreign keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/) (the interesting part is *The columns in the child table must be an index...*)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your suggestion of doing (messageID,messageContentCount). This fixed the problem at line 158, and later on at line 164, where the same error occurred.