# (Laravel) errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I try to migrate my tables but it display an error which is:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter
>   table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`))

This is my tables:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: I understand that the foreign key column and the referencing column were not of the same type but from what i know in Laravel documentation that increments is Incrementing ID (primary key) using a "UNSIGNED INTEGER" equivalent so i make the foreign key column as unsigned integer. I want to know how to fix it since i do what they want or maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @FahadAlDaferi actually it's not unsigned

Comment: For people looking some easy solution try renaming the filename, make sure the date for the parent table migration in filename comes before the table which has the foreign key. I think migrations are executed in increasing date order. Like: 2014, then 2015 and so on. This works assuming everything else in your migration is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you create the `users` table with a foreign key to the `roles` table, then the `roles` table does not exist yet, therefore you cannot add a foreign key referencing it.

I also noted that the `roles` table also has a foreign key referencing the `users` table, which makes the situation more tricky.

If you are absolutely sure that the `roles` table needs a foreign key to the `users` table, then you need to remove the foreign key creation from the `users` table definition, and add it separately back as `alter table` after the `roles` table is created.

However, I'm not sure that the `roles` table should have an fk to the `users` table (unless it represents the user that created the role) because you can have multiple users in a role. If you are modelling a many-to-many relationship, then this is not the way to do it. But this has got nothing to do with the current error, so treat this as a side note only.

Comment: Yes, you are right but let me explain what i want to do I have two roles 1 admin - 2 user and i want to assign one of them to each user becuase i want only admin users to login into backend dashboard as for now i make the relationship between roles and users as one(role)-to-many(users) so i need you help here

Comment: That's a different question from this altogether and you have to post it as such. As I explained in my answer, that was a side note. This question is about fk error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that error can also occur due to migrations order. If you face errno 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" then go to your migrations folder and check whether the parent table migration was executed first or not. If child table migration is executed first according to the migration order, it will try to find foreign key binding and shows that error.