# Auto_increment Column does not create while updating table query

Tags: mysql

I create a table whose query is

```
Create table unititem (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

than alter it by following query

```
 Alter table unititem AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I also have a table `tablename` and in want to alter it by adding a column `unitItemId` which references table `unititem`. The query which I want to execute is

```
Alter table tablename add column Unititemid INT NOT
NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

but when I execute this query it gives me this error:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

When I want to make it a foreign key then it gives `1005 error` on following query

```
Alter table tablename 
add column Unititemid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Unititemid) REFERENCES unititem (ID) ;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

**Update1**
As suggested I'm not adding `unititemid` as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN unititemid INT NOT NULL;
```

Now the problem is: how can I make it a foreign key? When i use the following query it gives an error:

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FOREIGN KEY  (unititemid) REFERENCES unititem(ID);
```

**Error:** Error Code: 1005
Can't create table 'alnasar_inventory.#sql-a04_1' (errno: 150)

howto resolve this issue ? Any Suggestions.

Comment: The primary key cannot also be a foreign key

Comment: @jacques sorry i have updated the information kindly take a look again

Comment: @jacques  i want to use id as a foreign key in another table but i don't know how i have search alot but did not get the job done

Comment: Could you copy the error message returned by MySql?

Comment: Ok I will show you @max meijer

Comment: @MaxMeijer error is Error Code: 1005 Can't create table 'alnasar_inventory.#sql-a04_1' (errno: 150)

Comment: Try looking at the answers in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error.

Comment: What is the result of running `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`?

Comment: Result means ? Did I have to run this query that you mentioned in your coment @maxMeijer

Comment: Yes. Result means output / return value. The query shows what kind of table it is and what its columns are. If you post that (or at least the relevant part of it), I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the query, simply remove `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Try:

```
Alter table tablename add column Unititemid INT NOT
NULL ;
```

You don't want (and cannot have) the foreign key to auto increment in your new table.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` exists to automatically generate a new unique id for your table row, but it doesn't make sense to use it on a foreign key.

Consider the table `unititem`. It has id's `1`,`2`,`3`. You also have 3 rows in `tablename` with `Unititemid`'s `1`,`2`,`3`. Now you create a new row in the other table `tablename`. How would you expect `AUTO_INCREMENT` to work here? It would auto increment `3` to `4` but that doesn't make any sense because there is no `4` in unititem. So `AUTO_INCREMENT` only makes sense on the original table, not on the other table.

Comment: Ok but when i  alter table add col Unititemid int not null and after this I make unititemid foreign kry ref unititem id than it gives 1005 error

Comment: What's the exact query you're trying?

Comment: After adding unititemid int not null in tablename  than i use the following alter table tablename add foreign key (unititemid) references unititem (ID) but this give error

Comment: Ok the tablename i'm using has many columns and i did not build tablename that is why i'm altering it and adding this column and it gives error like of same datatype, do you think there would be some restrictions in tablename to add a foreign key