# codeigniter migration error foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys, database-migration

i made a migration in my CI, now i have error in making some foreign key in it. How can i make some foreign key, i saw some questions here related to this topic but it doesn't solve my problem.

Here is my code where i got error:

```
public function up() {
         $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'student_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'INT',
                    'constraint' => 11,
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,
                    'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'course_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'INT',
                    'constraint' => 11,

            ),
            'fname' => array(
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => 50,                    
            ),
            'lname' => array (
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => 50,
            ),
            'gender' => array (
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => 1
            ),
            'bday' => array (
                    'type' => 'DATE'                    
            )
        ));
        $this->dbforge->add_key('student_id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->add_field('CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES tbl_course(id)');
        $this->dbforge->create_table('tbl_students');
```

it gives me an error of :

```
 Can't create table `student_db`.`tbl_students` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES tbl_course(id),
        CONSTRAINT `pk_tbl_students` PRIMARY KEY(`student_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: did you check if the foreign key column and the referencing column are the same type or length?

Comment: @Vickel do i need to make them thesame? thanks for fast reply

Comment: @Vickel hello sir. yes. i checked it, and its the same. here is it. 'id' => array(
                    'type' => 'INT',
                    'constraint' => 11,
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,
                    'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),

Comment: run through this post, you might find what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error

Comment: @Vickel its already the-same data type

Answer (score 0):

You needed to run the

```
dbforge->add_key
```

before the

```
dbforge->create_table
```

Something like this:

```
$this->dbforge->add_field('CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table(id)');

$this->dbforge->add_column('table',[
    'CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES table(id)',
]);
```