# Foreign key not being created MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a weird situation...I've got a sql query that *is* working on my production server, but *not* on the development server...here is the query in question:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sizes` (
  `size` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `sizes` (`size`, `id`) VALUES
('Small', 3),
('Medium', 3),
('Large', 3),
('Medium', 5),
('Large', 5),
('Large', 6),
('Extra Large', 6),
('Extra Large', 4);
ALTER TABLE `sizes`
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `sizes`
ADD CONSTRAINT `sizes_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`);
```

As you can see, I'm just trying to create a simple table that holds the sizes of products I have. I have two columns...the actual size and also a foreign key `id` that references my `products` table, and as you can imagine, references the id of the product the size goes to. The problem is on my *production* server, the query is executed perfectly and the relationship is established. But on my development server, I get this error message when I fire off the command:

```
Can't create table `thecovh1_lucy`.`#sql-1eed4_17bf` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Two things are confusing me here:
1. Why is it saying I'm trying to create a table named `#sql-1eed4_17bf`
And more importantly
2. What is wrong with the way I establish foreign keys?
For reference, I also tried this way of creating the table (without inserting data into the table, this was just trying to create the table):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sizes (
size VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
id INT(10) NOT NULL ,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES products(id));
```

Which is a way I created my `uiid` table (again, to success), but that is also giving me the exact same error message.

Comment: Check some of the things people tried in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error. Run a diff between your production database and development database to see if there are any differences, however slight, in the data types.

Comment: I ran to a similar problem where the character sets of two tables were different which caused the foreign key creation to fail. The strangely named table is most likely the name of the temporary table that the alter command created.