# mysql FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT failing when recreating

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I had already created the database and all `tables` with `foreign key constraints`, but I had a column in parent `table` which was `unique` and was part of composite `key`, so I had to `drop` all `foreign key constraints` from all child `tables` and then `drop`ped the `unique constraint` on parent `table`.

Now when I am adding `foreign key constraint` back to all child `tables`, it gives `error`: *`foreign key constraint` is incorrectly formed*, although I have checked both my parent and child `table columns` and they are of same `type` using same `engine`, `unicode` and all. But still this is thrown.

When I checked the `table` structure of child `table`, it has an `index` defined for the `foreign key` and the `column` is child `column foreign key`, so I tried after removing it but still `error`.

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE `child_table` ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY `fk_parent_table_child_table_column_name` (child_table_column_name) 
REFERENCES `parent_table`(parent_table_column_name) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

both `columns` are `VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL`

If more information is required please ask.

**EDIT**

So far I have tried to `drop`ped the `index`, `drop`ped the `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` from child `table` and `drop`ping the `column` then adding it back with `VARCHAR(14), NOT NULL`, still no success.

**EDIT 2**

Also tried to `add` the child `column` in `primary key` and then tried to apply `foreign key constraint`, no success so far.

Comment: Did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error ?

Comment: Yes I already did and tried several solutions but none worked, and I don't want to make my column a unique since I did all this because of it

Comment: could you show exact column definition for both table ?

Comment: I have already mentioned it

Comment: I said **exact**, I don't think your column would be just `varchar`. Just copy paste here

Comment: its `VARCHAR(14)` in both tables but the 14 in definition is meant to show this many characters on console it has nothing to do with datatype as most people think

Comment: Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments. Don't edit via addendums, make the best possible current presentation. Please read & act on [mcve]. That inclues cut & pasteable code plus input & output & explanation. Also read hits googling your error message including error number(s) with & without your particular names/code. See [ask]. PS If a unique column set is part of a composite key then you could & should have declared the column set to be the key. Only when a composite FK references a proper superset of a PK/UNIQUE do you also have to declare the superset as PK/UNIQUE.

Comment: I thought I already had explained enough to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered and I couldn't find a solution to my problem I had to drop the child foreign keys and then remove the parent composite key so as to remove the parent column which was VARCHAR(14) and then again create foreign keys with new primary key.