# While trying to alter a table in SQL, I get an error saying a comma is missing before the start of a new alter operation

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm creating a database for an assignment. When trying to alter a certain table to add a primary key and foreign key a certain error wont let me update the table.

I tried adding a comma at the end of the row which did not resolved the error. Tried to look it up on the internet but I didn't find any relevant information about what can be done to fix it except that it might be a bug.

```
CREATE TABLE aircraft_model(
    Aircraft_model_ID INT,
    Model INT,
    Manufacture VARCHAR(40),
    Range_nmi INT,
    Range_km INT,
    Length INT,
    Width INT,
    Height INT
);

ALTER TABLE aircraft_model
ADD CONSTRAINT Aircraft_model_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY (Aircraft_model_ID)
ADD CONSTRAINT  Manufacture_fk FOREIGN KEY (Manufacture) REFERENCES Aircraft_Manufacture(Manufacture_ID);
```

This is what I'm getting after I run the code:

Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

> Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "PRIMARY KEY" at position 64)
>   SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE aircraft_model ADD CONSTRAINT Aircraft_model_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY (Aircraft_model_ID) ADD CONSTRAINT Manufacture_fk FOREIGN KEY (Manufacture) REFERENCES Aircraft_Manufacture(Manufacture_ID)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT  Manufacture_fk FOREIGN KEY (Manufacture) REFERENCES Aircraft_Man' at line 3

Comment: What error do you get after adding the comma in? Is it the same "Missing comma" message?

Comment: after adding a comma at the end I get the following error: #1005 - Can't create table `jetairline`.`#sql-4b28_243` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Ok, is the `jetairline` table in that error message the same as the `aircraft_model` table in your example above or some other table? Take a look at this post and see if any of the answers there work for you: [mysql foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: jetairline is the name of the database in which the aircraft_model table is created. I have not created any other tables or used the same name for anything else except for the database name.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers on the SO post I linked? For example, is the `Manufacture_ID` in the `Aircraft_Manufacture` table a VARCHAR(40) with a UNIQUE index?

Comment: I tried most of the solutions presented in there and the error still popps up when I run the code. I'm starting to think it might be a bug.

Comment: Ok, would you mind also posting the schema of the Aircraft_Manufacture table so we can see if anything looks amiss?

Comment: Thank you for help, I managed to fix the problem. I had mistakenly declared Manufacture as a VARCHAR in the aircraft_model table when I should have declared it as an INT.

Comment: No problem! Make sure you add the Aircraft_Manufacture schema to the original post and write up an answer so that people can benefit from this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine when I try it:

```
ALTER TABLE aircraft_model
    ADD CONSTRAINT Aircraft_model_ID_pk PRIMARY KEY (Aircraft_model_ID),
    ADD CONSTRAINT  Manufacture_fk FOREIGN KEY (Manufacture) REFERENCES Aircraft_Manufacture(Manufacture_ID);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=02c4396d8dd68e7865dde1c246b78753) is a db<>fiddle.