# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" how can i fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have been trying it on different ways, but i can not get the error away. so my question is: Can anyone else see the mistake is made?

this is my code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->boolean('admin')->default('0');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('places', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('location_name');
        $table->string('village');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('planning', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->unsignedInteger('places_id');
        $table->time('van');
        $table->time('tot');
        $table->date('dag');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedInteger('created_by');

        $table->foreign('places_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('places')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('created_by')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

}
```

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
>   table `foodtruck`.`#sql-3be8_b8` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
>   is incorrectly formed" )")

I want this error message to leave my command line and my migration file to be fixed on a way i can use it normally :)

Comment: Where are you creating the table `foodtruck`?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error), as one of its answers may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `places_id` and `created_by` are defined as `bigIncrements`, you cannot define their foriegn keys as `unsignedInteger` it needs to be the corresponding data type which according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/migrations#creating-columns) is:

> Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key) equivalent column.

which is equivalent to `unsignedBigInteger`.

Change,

```
$table->unsignedInteger('places_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('created_by');
```

To,

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('places_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by');
```