# Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint - mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a self-referencing `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on a table (comment):

```
SET
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = OFF;

ALTER TABLE
`comment` ADD CONSTRAINT comment_parent_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES `comment`(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And I get this error:

> **#1825 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'comment'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'databasename/comment_parent_id_foreign'**

Earlier I accidentally added this `constraint` on an unintended table (post). I wasn't able to delete the constraint, so I removed the column (parent_id) itself. I created this column again. And now I'm not able to add this self-referencing constraint.

Both have same datatype `bigint(20)` (id and parent_id) and comment`id` is a primary key

Table is using `InnoDB` engine

Here's my table structure:

[image]

thanks

Comment: awghad distay !!

Comment: which database ae you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... ?

Comment: @damadam I'm using mysql

Comment: I don't really know if you really had named your table `comment` with `\`` quote, probably it would works better without them : `ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT comment_parent_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES comment (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

' The size and sign of integer types must be the same' - dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html - change so that both are unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

1.***Engine*** should be the same e.g. InnoDB

2.***Datatype*** should be the same, and with same length. e.g. VARCHAR(50)

3.***Collation*** Columns charset should be the same. e.g. utf-8

4.***Unique*** - Foreign key should refer to field that is unique  in the reference table

5.***Nullable*** If the constraint's action is `SET NULL`, make sure that the column is *nullable*.

Comment: ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT fk_comment_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES comment(id);

Comment: can you try this @JayWadhwa

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from Google: If you have this in your query, ensure that the column is nullable.

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT fk_comment_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES comment(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find the reason for the error, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64251639/1119601) to get more details about the error:

```sql
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

And in the output search for `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`.

Credits go to **[@sidonai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4568250/sidonai).**