# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have this error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `shreemad`.`posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Table 1:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('type_id');
        $table->string('product_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('type');
        $table->foreign('type')->references('type_id')->on('category');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('price')->nullable();
        $table->mediumtext('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: The reference must be the primary key of the category table. And at it's id. $table->foreign('type')->references('id')->on('category');

Comment: You have to include an onDelete and on Update method on your foreign key field. And also if that does not do it check for how order of your migrations.the category migrations should be before the posts migrations.

Comment: Make sure that you have a proper order of your migrations, like first category and then posts. Order matters

Answer (score 0):

You have to include an onDelete and on Update method on your foreign key field.

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('type');
    $table->foreign('type')->references('type_id')->on('category')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

And also if that does not do it check for how order of your migrations.the category migrations should be before the posts migrations.