# constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE casting 
(
   idFilms INT,
   idActeur INT,
   roles varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   primary key (idFilms, idActeur),
   FOREIGN KEY (idFilms) REFERENCES films(id),    
   FOREIGN KEY (idActeur) REFERENCES acteur(id)  
);
```

I keep getting this error

> #1005 - Can't create table `fabrizioestrellatp1`.`casting` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Need some help please

Comment: What is your RDBMS ? (oracle, mysql, sqlserver, postgres...) ?

Comment: also you are missing the constraint word `CONSTRAINT fk_somename FOREIGN KEY (idFilms) REFERENCES films (id)` also make sure the types of the columns matches

Comment: Have you looked at the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8434518/73226

Comment: @JorgeCampos You can declare a foreign key without a name if it's directly on a column `idFilms INT FOREIGN KEY (idFilms) references films(id),`

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, you are right, I should not have said missing, i meant more like that the constraint will be created with a random name, it is better to define one...

Comment: @Charlieface: you can also declare the foreign key without a name at the end of the CREATE statement (at least in standard SQL): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d6c7e15b6e7b2fcf0802e252d996eb33 Note that MySQL silently ignores inline foreign keys. So if you use `idfilms int references ...` in MySQL you are left **without** a foreign key.

Comment: This  CREATE TABLE is valid, as long as the films and acteur tables both have the corresponding keys required.

Comment: Your code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=122686efffc095e2a6239115aced9062.  I'm voting to close.