# Can't create table with foreign key Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys

I'm having hard time creating a table in maria db with foreign key and I can't figure it out.
I got that message : "Can't create table `evanightdb`.`events_liked` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")".

The table I try to create :

```
CREATE TABLE events_liked (
    id INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_events int(11),
    title_event text,
    event_liked int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ID,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_events) REFERENCES event_details(`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (title_event) REFERENCES event_details(`title`)
    )
```

And this is the table "event_details".

```
CREATE TABLE `event_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_image_url` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_path` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_1` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_2` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_by` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time_not_parsed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `going` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `interested` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`);

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Did you try to create `events_liked` before `event_details` exists?

Comment: I also notice `event_details` does not have a PRIMARY KEY constraint on its `id` column. You need that.

Comment: And you can't make a foreign key on a `TEXT` column.

Comment: You might like to read this checklist of foreign key requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673775/20860

Comment: Actually ID has unique key defined already. I exported from SQL file and forgot that I altered the table.
So here the constraints : 
ALTER TABLE `event_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`);

I didn't try to create events_liked before, why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB

> `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns cannot be used as foreign keys

[Knowledge Base » MariaDB Server Documentation » High Availability & Performance Tuning » Optimization and Tuning » Optimization and Indexes » Foreign Keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/)

---

Possible solution 1: add generated column of VARCHAR(xxx) datatype which is assigned with the prefix of `TEXT` column then use it for FK.

Possible solution 2: add generated column of proper datatype which is assigned with some hash of `TEXT` column then use it for FK.

Both solutions assumes that generated column is created in both tables.