# MySQL create table: error 1005 errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”

Tags: mysql, laravel

why laravel schema reply:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `employee_management`.`employees` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
> is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `employees` add constraint
> `employees_city_id_foreign` foreign key (`city_id`) references `city`
> (`id`))
>
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
> table `employee_management`.`employees` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed")")

My Table:

```
  Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id', true);
            $table->string('lastname', 60);
            $table->string('firstname', 60);
            $table->string('middlename', 60);
            $table->string('address', 120);
            $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();;
            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('city');
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('state');
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('country');
            $table->char('zip', 10);
            $table->integer('age')->unsigned();
            $table->date('birthdate');
            $table->date('date_hired');
            $table->integer('department_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('division_id')->unsigned();
            // $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('department');
            $table->foreign('division_id')->references('id')->on('division');
            // $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
            $table->string('picture', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

My second table for city:

```
Schema::create('city', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id', true);
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('state');
            $table->string('name', 60);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

P.S. My Laravel version is 8.12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Creating tables with Foreign Keys giving errno: 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is you are trying to migrate `employee` table before creating `city` table and this matters because your `employee` table depends on the `city` table by foreign key.

To solve that first try to migrate city table.