# SQL FOREIGN KEY ERROR (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Hi I have this three very simple tables but I can't fix it to get the right format of foreign key.

CREATE TABLE company(
company_name varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
bid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
cid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES branch(branch_id),
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contact(contact_id)
);

CREATE TABLE  branch(
branch_id INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
branch_type varchar(30),
cid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (branch_id),
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contact(contact_id)
);

CREATE TABLE contact(
contact_id INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
fst_name varchar(20),
mdl_name varchar(20),
lst_name varchar(20),
sex varchar(20),
dob DATE,
phone_number INT(15),
address varchar(255),
email varchar(255),
bid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (contact_id),
FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES branch (branch_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

All three of them have the same error150.
Thank you so much for helping.[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxLT.png)

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. A question re how you are 1st stuck will be a duplicate. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See the edit help re inline & block code & quotations & line breaks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `company` table reference the `branch` and `contact` table before they are created.
Also, the branch table references the contact table and vice versa so the database goes like that:

Creating the `contact` table ... there is a `bid` field connected to a table named `branch` ... table branch does not exist -> error

You have to create the `contact` table first but ***without the foreign id reference to bid***, then create `branch` table and then `company` table.
After you have your tables all set you can execute another query to add a foreign id reference to bid.

So Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact( contact_id INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE, fst_name varchar(20), mdl_name varchar(20), lst_name varchar(20), sex varchar(20), dob DATE, phone_number INT(15), address varchar(255), email varchar(255), bid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (contact_id) )ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE branch( branch_id INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE, branch_type varchar(30), cid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY (branch_id), FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contact(contact_id) );


CREATE TABLE company( company_name varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL, bid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE, cid INT(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES branch(branch_id), FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contact(contact_id) );
```

Notice I removed `FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES branch (branch_id)`
And then:

```
ALTER TABLE contact ADD FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES branch(branch_id);
```

**P.S Run the commands in the same order**