# Creating SQL foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to reference admins table to activity log table but it is failing yet i have correctly formed it.

BELOW IS THE SQL ERROR

Error

```
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE activity_log_admins ADD FOREIGN KEY (adminid) REFERENCES admins(adminid)

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table `miu`.`activity_log_admins` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Please help me how to figure it out?

Comment: Show us admins and activity_log_admins table definitions.

Comment: Is your column adminid in table admins primary key ?

Comment: Either the datatypes are not the same or the tables contains the data which contradicts this relation.

Comment: adminid is the primary key in the admins table

Comment: Please add both table definitions or read the manual and figure it out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error

Comment: Thanks stackoverflow article was usefull by just changing parent table to InnoDB Engine ALTER TABLE parent_table ENGINE=InnoDB;