# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" Trying to make a old project work

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, foreign-keys

So i'm trying to make a old project work again but when i put back my tables to the new database i'm having this issue

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 777: Can't create table `****`.`#sql-3f2_45` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

There is the table that causing problems:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `install__dashboards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `zone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `object` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` set('dashboard','visualization','search') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```sql
--
-- Contraintes pour la table `install__dashboards`
--
ALTER TABLE `install__dashboards`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_agent` FOREIGN KEY (`agent`) REFERENCES `install__agents` (`name`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_proto` FOREIGN KEY (`protocol`) REFERENCES `install__ports` (`protocol`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_zone` FOREIGN KEY (`zone`) REFERENCES `install__zone` (`slug`);
```

References tables :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `install__agents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `OS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IP` text,
  `isLog` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `install__ports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isUDP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `machine` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `install__zone` (
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('notpresent','installing','installed') NOT NULL,
  `options` text,
  `IPrange` text,
  `IPsystem` text,
  `system` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Some of the referenced tables columns has diff data type?

Comment: Are the two columns you're trying to connect of the same type and length? According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error) that could be the problem.

Comment: I have edited with references tables

Comment: There are no indexes on the install__tables?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the error message isn't very descriptive :-(

To get more details about the cause of the error, just check InnoDB status:

```
$ mysql -e"SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G"  | grep -C3 "FOREIGN KEY ERROR"


SEMAPHORES
----------
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2022-12-06 11:08:12 0x7f43a80ba700 Error in foreign key constraint of table `test`.`install__dashboards`:
Alter  table `test`.`install__dashboards` with foreign key `dash_proto` constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.------------
```

So the problem/reason is `There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [indexes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b62130) on the referencing column:

```
CREATE INDEX `ix_install__agents_name` ON `install__agents` (`name`);
CREATE INDEX `ix_install__ports_protocol` ON `install__ports` (`protocol`);
CREATE INDEX `ix_install__zone_slug` ON `install__zone` (`slug`);
```

but your schema does not look right. It's better to have the `ID` of the entity.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `install__agents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `OS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IP` text,
  `isLog` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `install__ports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `numero` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isUDP` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `machine` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `install__zone` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('notpresent','installing','installed') NOT NULL,
  `options` text,
  `IPrange` text,
  `IPsystem` text,
  `system` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `install__dashboards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `protocol_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_id` int(11)DEFAULT  NULL,
  `object` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` set('dashboard','visualization','search') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `install__dashboards`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_agent` FOREIGN KEY (`agent_id`) REFERENCES `install__agents` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_proto` FOREIGN KEY (`protocol_id`) REFERENCES `install__ports` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dash_zone` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `install__zone` (`id`);
```