# Table exported with phpmyadmin can't be reimported

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have two servers, a dev and a prod kind of, with the same softwares installed on them. I want to export the db from prod to dev, so i used phpMyadmin, but when reimporting the sql on the dev server, an error occurs:

```
#1005 - Can't create table `omekas`.`asset` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```

This really surprises me, as i expected this process to be sort of automatic. What did i do wrong ?

Here is the Create table throwing the error:

```
    --
-- Table structure for table `asset`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asset`;
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `media_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `storage_id` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_text` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Constraints for table `asset`
--
ALTER TABLE `asset`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_2AF5A5C7E3C61F9` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the "user" table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_hash` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

edit 2:

I tried to create the table without the foreign key constraint at all, removing the alter table... Which still gave me the same error ?

Running

```
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `media_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `storage_id` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_text` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Returns

```
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `media_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `storage_id` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_text` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table `omekas`.`asset` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```

Comment: Are you using different versions/products?

Comment: can you share the user structure

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error

Comment: how about if you do `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` before restoring and resetting it to 1 again?

Comment: @s.abbaasi didn't worked :( thanks anyway

Comment: @jarlh Normally no, since dev is a clone of prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved, but sadly not by an useful mean. I dropped the entire db and reimported it, and this time Mariadb didn't complained. Maybe this question is better deleted